# How do you add a newline between section number and section title?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, titlesec

Basically I want something to look like:

**1**

**Section title**

I'm using the `titlesec` package.

Also on another note, I managed to get my subsubsections to not show without any numbering as 1.1.2 (as is required for my report). But on the Table of Contents, it still shows the 1.2.2 numbering. How do I remove this, and make the subsubsection title aligned with the title of the subsection in the Table of Contents?

My code so far:

```
\def\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\def\thesubsubsection{}

\renewcommand{\thesection} {\arabic{section}\newline }

\titleformat{\section}{\Huge\bfseries\newline}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries\newline}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\bfseries}{}{}{}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This question will make us guess around. Please provide some minimal and compilable code which we can look at for you. "managed to get [...] without any numbering" could be anything. No chance to help like this. Thank you. Btw. there are many posts on [tag:titlesec] on this site. Many of them show examples of your desired result.

Comment: Please read how to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`, and not just be a code snippet. We want to copy-and-paste-and-compile and replicate the problems you're experiencing. That's the best way for the community to start helping you.

Comment: The solution is based on the class in use, you should add a small example to your question. Some classes are incompatible with `titlesec` (or rather vice versa, titlesec can't cope with the classes).

Answer (score 2):

By using the `display` shape provided by `titlesec` you can set the vertical spacing between the number and title without having to redefine everything. Also, you can get un-numbered `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` by using the starred variant (see MWE). This will also hide them from `tableofcontents`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thesection}{5pt}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{Section title}
Text goes here

\subsection*{Subsection title}
Section not numbered

\subsubsection*{Subsection title}
Subsection not numbered either
\end{document}
```

[image]